# Unlit shader issue with fog in Unity's Univeral Render Pipeline

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d-rendering

**Edit**
I figured out a tempoary fix for my initial question "*how to disable this weird fog*": Disable the fog in the **lighting pannel** (genius, right ?)

However, since I might need fog later, and it does not behave as I would expect, I still need to fix this issue.

**Note**: This only happens with exponential fog modes, not with linear.

---

I'm having issues with unity's universal render pipeline: A light grey fog, whose strength depends on the camera heading (see [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XB2HTGpLoE2RdlRVU61nOznYLqS5Cq_J/view?usp=sharing))

[image: Unity rendering issue]
(see how the plane geometry affects the fog)

The steps to reproduce are very simple (or just download the project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pzbjabeCNomT2YrWETjr4jR13wNx-2Io/view?usp=sharing)):

- Create a universal render pipeline project
- Delete the "example assets" from the scene
- Create a floor with a quad (create quad, rotate, scale)
- Create a new material

  - Shader: URP / unlit
  - Base map: black

That's it.
Rotate around, see how the "unlit" plane is actually affected by a fog whose strength depends on the heading of the camera

- Rotating the quad has the same effect as rotating the camera.
- Rotating the directionnal light has no effect (except on the skybox)
- Removing the Directionnal light has no effect (except on the skybox)
- Removing the Post processing volume makes the "fog" stronger in all directions so the camera heading effect is less noticeable but still there
- This happens in game mode as well as in the editor
- Getting close to the ground makes the fog lighter
- the camera position has an impact as well (this is more visible when testing with a plane rather than a quad)

system info:

- tested on unity versions: 2019.4.18f1, 2019.4.20f1 (LTS), 2020.2.1f1
- Windows 10 Home 19042.804

Is it possible this is a bug in the URP/unlit shader ?

Thanks for any help!